# Is there anything similar to Chrome's fileSystem API for Firefox addons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have made a Chrome app that relies heavily on Chrome's fileSystem API to record and save video streams from various websites. Since the stream data is processed in javascript before being saved, simply downloading the streams doesn't work.

Now I am considering making a Firefox version...

I know that Firefox has a `sandboxed` file system API, but as far as I know, it is not possible to save the files to the physical file system.

Only option I can see is creating a blob from the sandboxed file system and download that blob.

I have actually two questions:

1. Are there any options I have missed to create and save files directly in the physical file system from Firefox addons?
2. Even if I have to rely on the sandboxed file system, is it possible to open files in append mode, ie. to append data to existing files?

Comment: Yes to your first question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file Opening a file returns a stream and you have the doc for using a stream (the examples are about files): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_byte-streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to your first question: there is the [io/file](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file) API. Opening a file returns a stream ([io/bytestream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_byte-streams)). Examples from the docs

```
function readBinaryDataFromFile (filename) {
  var fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");
  var data = null;
  if (fileIO.exists(filename)) {
    var ByteReader = fileIO.open(filename, "rb");
    if (!ByteReader.closed) {
      data = ByteReader.read();
      ByteReader.close();
    }
  }
  return data;
}

function writeBinaryDataToFile(data, filename) {
  var fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");
  var ByteWriter = fileIO.open(filename, "wb");
  if (!ByteWriter.closed) {
    ByteWriter.write(data);
    ByteWriter.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And on the linked page I read this: "it is not possible to open the file in append mode." So currently my app cannot be ported to Firefox.

Comment: Firefox has extensions for years, what I linked is the new API, the legacy API is still there and there are hundreds of extensions manipulating files with no issue. Another doc link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm#openFileOutputStream%28%29 Another one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O

Comment: Thanks for the update. You are indeed right, there are extensions manipulating files. I found SQLite Manager which certainly reads and writes files on the local filesystem.